How to run a application (.exe) in PowerShell Script?
How to open or run an application using powershell script, ".ps1"?

It is unclear where you are referring to and what you expect as an answer knowing that there are many ways to run an applicatiion and there is no background. Please see: how to ask.

Unfortunately, PowerShell's documentation has no conceptual topic dedicated to invoking external (native) programs as of this writing. GitHub issue #5152 proposes introducing one, tentatively named "about_Native_Calls"; for now, the linked issue also provides a high-level summary of what should be documented.

What happens if you simply type the name of the executable (including its full path, of course)?

The only line needed is:
Start-Process -FilePath "MyExecutable.exe"

Save this line into a file ending in extension .ps1
To open a file use:
& .\myFile.txt


It is unclear what you want to brief here as usually & .\myFile.txt will open the app associatied with the .txt extention and you my just start your app with MyExecutable.See: how to answer.

To synchronously execute console applications or batch files in the current console (terminal), call them directly (some.exe or c:\path\to\some.exe ... or & 'c:\path with spaces\to\some.exe' ... or & $exePathStoredInVariable ...). This also allows you to capture their output directly and to later query their exit code via $LASTEXITCODE. Do not use Start-Process (or the System.Diagnostics.Process API it is based on). See this answer and this guidance.
